# Importing A table from phpMyAdmin to a server

Tags: mysql

I am trying to import a table from phpMyAdmin in my laptop to a server and I get this error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Rar!' at line 1

Comment: could you share the first line of the sql file you exported from phpmyadmin?

Comment: You need to provide more information. Your question is really broad now. Which query did you tried?